# Constructing A Truth Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I construct a truth table with a formula that has 3 logical operators that lack a parentheses?
$$P \lor Q \land \neg(R \lor \neg S)$$

Comment: Under "~" you mean negation? "V" is "or"? "Λ" is "and"?

Comment: Yes negation is ~ and V is or and Λ is and

Comment: I inserted formatting - is it now what you asked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally
$$P \lor Q \land \neg(R \lor \neg S)$$ is same as  $$P \lor (Q \land (\neg(R \lor (\neg S))))$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thanks man this is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish where the parentheses are to make a truth table.  The truth values of
$P \vee (Q \wedge R)$ and $(P \vee Q) \wedge R$ can be different.  Maybe your environment has a standard for whether $\vee$ binds tighter than $\wedge$, in which case you know.  If not, you don't.  I don't know what is standard, but I assume they are equal and parentheses are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The only hint i got was "be mindful of the precedence of logical operators".

Comment: The precedence would be which operator binds more tightly.  I don't know which one does for your class.  If $\wedge$ binds more tightly you should read it as the first of my examples.